# Проблемка с простым кодом. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, прошу помочь js джедаев в решение проблемы. Есть такой массив, функции указаны в prompt. Несколько раз переписывал код и теперь он вовсе не загружается. Буду очень благодарен.

Массивы

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ask() {
        var conf;
            do {
                list =    { 
                    name: prompt("Введите свое имя:"),
                    sname: prompt("Введите свою фамилию:"),
                    age: +prompt("Введите свой возраст:"),  
                    sex: prompt("Введите свой пол:"),
                    codelang: prompt("Введите языки програмирования которые вы знаете:"),
                        };
                    list.push(list); 
                    cl.push(list.codelang)
                    conf = confirm("Продолжить?"); 
                    }
            while (conf != false);  
        }

    function say() {
        var i;
        for (i = 4; i < list.length; i++) {
            document.write("Имя: " + list[i].name + "<br />");
            document.write("Фамилия: " + list[i].sname + "<br />");
            document.write("Возраст: " + list[i].age + "<br />");
            document.write("Пол: " + list[i].sex + "<br />");
            document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[i] + "<br />");
            document.write("<hr/>");
                };
        }

    function deli() {
        var index = +prompt("Введите номер индекса который вы хотели бы удалить");              
            list.splice(index, 1);
            cl.splice(index, 1);
    }

    function deln() {
        var name = prompt("Введите имя человека которого вы хотели бы удалить");
        for (i = 4; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (name === list[i].name ) {
                list.splice(i, 1)
                };
            else if (name === list[1].name || name === list[2].name || name === list[3].name)
                break;
            }

    function readylist() {
        document.write("Имя: " + list[1].name + "<br />");
        document.write("Фамилия: " + list[1].sname + "<br />");
        document.write("Возраст: " + list[1].age + "<br />");
        document.write("Пол: " + list[1].sex + "<br />");
        document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[1] + "<br />");
        document.write("<hr/>");

        document.write("Имя: " + list[2].name + "<br />");
        document.write("Фамилия: " + list[2].sname + "<br />");
        document.write("Возраст: " + list[2].age + "<br />");
        document.write("Пол: " + list[2].sex + "<br />");
        document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[2] + "<br />");
        document.write("<hr/>");

        document.write("Имя: " + list[3].name + "<br />");
        document.write("Фамилия: " + list[3].sname + "<br />");
        document.write("Возраст: " + list[3].age + "<br />");
        document.write("Пол: " + list[3].sex + "<br />");
        document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[3] + "<br />");
        document.write("<hr/>");

    }

    function compare(a, b) {
            if (a.name < b.name)
            return -1;
            if (a.name > b.name)
            return 1;
            return 0;
            }

   var list = [{
        name: '',
        sname: '',
        age:'',
        sex: '',
        codelang: '',
        },{
        name: "Дмитрий",
        sname: "Вернадский",
        age: 30,
        sex: "Мужской",
        codelang: ["html, css, php"],
        },{
        name: "Андрей",
        sname: "Сорока",
        age: 21,
        sex: "Мужской",
        codelang: ["html, css, php"],
        },{
        name: "Татьяна",
        sname: "Ситало",
        age: 24,
        sex: "Женский",
        codelang: ["html, css, php"],
        }]; 

    cl[1] = list.codelang[1];
    cl[2] = list.codelang[2];
    cl[3] = list.codelang[3];

    var func = prompt("Меню: 1 - добавить человека в очередь, 2 - посмотреть весь список добавленных, 3.1 - удалить человека по имени, 3.2 - удалить человека по индексу, 4.1 - сортировка массива по имени, 4.2 - сортировка массива по количеству языков програмирования, 4.3 - сортировка массива по возрасту, 5 - выход с программы");

        switch (func) {
        case "1":
        {
            readylist();
            ask();
            say();
        }
        break;
        case "2":   
        {
            readylist();
            say();
        }
        break;
        case "3.1": 
        {
            deln();
            readylist();   

        }
        break;
        case "3.2":
        {
            deli();
            readylist();   

        }
        break;
        case "4.1":
        {

            list.sort(compare);
            readylist();   
        }
        break;
        case "4.2":
        {
            cl.sort(function(a, b){
            return b.length - a.length;
            });
            readylist();
        }
        break;
        case "4.3":
        {
            function compare(a, b) {
            return a.age - b.age;
            }
            list.sort(compare);
            readylist();
        }
        break;
        case "5":
        {
            alert("До свидания!");
        }
    } 

</script>
```

Comment: я бы на вашем месте укоротил код до минимального возможно, та простыня, что есть, нереальна к пониманию

Comment: У вас 2 ошибки , которые видны прямо в браузере. 1ая - в блоке if else . После if (name=== list[i].name){} стоит ; которая не нужна. Вторая - нет закрывающей скобки в функции в конце скрипта

Comment: Из [справки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: Поиск ошибок в коде. Прежде чем спрашивать «почему у меня не работает вот этот (простыня из тысячи строк) код?» постарайтесь сами локализовать проблему, ...

Comment: Рекомендую избегать использования `document.write`, уж 2016 год на дворе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var list = [{
      name: '',
      sname: '',
      age: '',
      sex: '',
      codelang: '',
    }, {
      name: "Дмитрий",
      sname: "Вернадский",
      age: 30,
      sex: "Мужской",
      codelang: ["html, css, php"],
    }, {
      name: "Андрей",
      sname: "Сорока",
      age: 21,
      sex: "Мужской",
      codelang: ["html, css, php"],
    }, {
      name: "Татьяна",
      sname: "Ситало",
      age: 24,
      sex: "Женский",
      codelang: ["html, css, php"],
    }];

    cl[1] = list[1].codelang;
    cl[2] = list[2].codelang;
    cl[3] = list[3].codelang;

    var func = prompt("Меню: 1 - добавить человека в очередь, 2 - посмотреть весь список добавленных, 3.1 - удалить человека по имени, 3.2 - удалить человека по индексу, 4.1 - сортировка массива по имени, 4.2 - сортировка массива по количеству языков програмирования, 4.3 - сортировка массива по возрасту, 5 - выход с программы");

    switch (func) {
      case "1":
        {
          readylist();
          ask();
          say();
        }
        break;
      case "2":
        {
          readylist();
          say();
        }
        break;
      case "3.1":
        {
          deln();
          readylist();

        }
        break;
      case "3.2":
        {
          deli();
          readylist();

        }
        break;
      case "4.1":
        {

          list.sort(compare);
          readylist();
        }
        break;
      case "4.2":
        {
          cl.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.length - a.length;
          });
          readylist();
        }
        break;
      case "4.3":
        {
          function compare(a, b) {
            return a.age - b.age;
          }
          list.sort(compare);
          readylist();
        }
        break;
      case "5":
        {
          alert("До свидания!");
        }
    }
})
var cl = [];

function ask() {
  var conf;
  do {
    list = {
      name: prompt("Введите свое имя:"),
      sname: prompt("Введите свою фамилию:"),
      age: +prompt("Введите свой возраст:"),
      sex: prompt("Введите свой пол:"),
      codelang: prompt("Введите языки програмирования которые вы знаете:"),
    };
    list.push(list);
    cl.push(list.codelang)
    conf = confirm("Продолжить?");
  }
  while (conf != false);
}

function say() {
  var i;
  for (i = 4; i < list.length; i++) {
    document.write("Имя: " + list[i].name + "<br />");
    document.write("Фамилия: " + list[i].sname + "<br />");
    document.write("Возраст: " + list[i].age + "<br />");
    document.write("Пол: " + list[i].sex + "<br />");
    document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[i] + "<br />");
    document.write("<hr/>");
  };
}

function deli() {
  var index = +prompt("Введите номер индекса который вы хотели бы удалить");
  list.splice(index, 1);
  cl.splice(index, 1);
}

function deln() {
    var name = prompt("Введите имя человека которого вы хотели бы удалить");
    for (i = 4; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (name === list[i].name) {
        list.splice(i, 1)
      } else if (name === list[1].name || name === list[2].name || name === list[3].name)
        break;
    }

    function readylist() {
      document.write("Имя: " + list[1].name + "<br />");
      document.write("Фамилия: " + list[1].sname + "<br />");
      document.write("Возраст: " + list[1].age + "<br />");
      document.write("Пол: " + list[1].sex + "<br />");
      document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[1] + "<br />");
      document.write("<hr/>");

      document.write("Имя: " + list[2].name + "<br />");
      document.write("Фамилия: " + list[2].sname + "<br />");
      document.write("Возраст: " + list[2].age + "<br />");
      document.write("Пол: " + list[2].sex + "<br />");
      document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[2] + "<br />");
      document.write("<hr/>");

      document.write("Имя: " + list[3].name + "<br />");
      document.write("Фамилия: " + list[3].sname + "<br />");
      document.write("Возраст: " + list[3].age + "<br />");
      document.write("Пол: " + list[3].sex + "<br />");
      document.write("Языки програмирования: " + cl[3] + "<br />");
      document.write("<hr/>");

    }

    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

   
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2 Ошибки - После if (name=== list[i].name){} стоит ; которая не нужна. Вторая - нет закрывающей скобки в функции в конце скрипта .

**UPD**
В коде много мелких ошибок, которые полезно будет поправить самому автору для получения опыта =)

Comment: Он также не работает

Comment: Это массив который открывается в меню которое предполагает несколько функций. var func = prompt("Меню: 1 - добавить человека в очередь, 2 - посмотреть весь список добавленных, 3.1 - удалить человека по имени, 3.2 - удалить человека по индексу, 4.1 - сортировка массива по имени, 4.2 - сортировка массива по количеству языков програмирования, 4.3 - сортировка массива по возрасту, 5 - выход с программы");

Comment: Обновил код - смотрите. Вам бы немного больше почитать про js и про работу с массивами т.к. сl[1]=list.codelang[1] неверное в вашем контексте т.к. list это уже массив. У него как у объекта нет свойства codelang, которое вы определелили у **элемента** массива.

Comment: Второй момент - нумерация в массиве всегда начинается с 0 элемента. В вашем случае элементы по 0 индексу всегда пусты.

Comment: В целом ваш код надо еще много раз рефакторить, но это вы попытайтесь сделать сначала сами т.к. дав вам решения я вам только вред нанесу. P.S. Я использую в начале кода JQuery в 1ой строке ($(document).ready ) - она означает следующее: "Я запущу содержимое моего тела (функции) сразу же после того, как загрузится страница".

Comment: @AndrewS. Пишите сюда же, если у вас получится что-то еще изменить и вы застрянете. Я постараюсь помочь вам.